# Often need to rebuild project

Tags: java, compiler-errors, intellij-idea

Time to time when I run compiling in IDEA12 I get message about non-exists 100 errors (seemingly it's max showed errors) : for example Blabla.java cannot find symbol: class Blabla1, but when I open this file in IDE I don't see any compile errors. To eliminate this errors I should make rebuild project and then I don't get above errors. I didn't see such errors in IDEA11. Can anybody explain me why do I get this errors?

Sorry for my English. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen if you delete the `.class` files, for example, if you run a clean outside IDEA.

Even if the clean is the first step in an ant/mvn compile step, IDEA still seems to get confused until you run a rebuild.

Comment: IDEA 12 doesn't monitor output folders for external modifications for the performance reasons. It will detect the entire output being removed, but not the individual files.